# MySql syntax in SQL Server to set display length of datatype

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

We got some SQL scripts, some of them are using Syntax like :

```
    Create procedure procABC(...)
    as
    begin
    ...
    ...
    'ColA'= CONVERT(smalldatetime(10),ColB,103),
    ...
    ...
    End
```

Same kind of syntax we also have for INTEGER like

```
    INTEGER(5)
```

I know that this kind of syntax is used in MySql to set display width of a column or variable. But In any of the SQL Server version starting from SQL 7 to SQL 2008 this syntax fails.So my question is :

1. We have got this script from a SQL server machine as a backup, is it possible to have some kind of cached scripts, like we have in ORACLE where script may be invalid but still it will be on the server in invalid mode and will give compilation error if there are any syntax errors..
2. Is there anyway to achieve same kind of functionality in SQL server as we are supposed to re-create these objects **(Something other then SUBSTRING)** .

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to copy a database from MySQL to SQL Server; copy it in the other direction; develop an application that can use either MySQL or SQL Server as the backend; or something else?

Comment: No, I am not trying to copy from MySql to SQl Server. I am trying to migrate SQL server 2000 to Sql server 2008. So I had this syntax in some scripts. But now when I am trying the same scripts on Sql2000 they are failing and hence I am not able to migrate. I don't know how they could have been created in first place.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, why did you mention MySQL? And if you are upgrading your SQL Server version why are you using scripts? Why not just install the new version and let it do the upgrade? Scripts that use SQL Server 2008 features will obviously not run on SQL Server 2000, but the reverse is possible.

Comment: This is migration and the syntax which I mentioned is allowed in MySql. So What I am thinking is initially the client database may had been in MySql then they switched to Sql Server. There is no way of directly upgrading scripts by just installing the newer version. We are supposed to migrate the scripts and If its running on Sql2000 then it should also run on Sql2008 that is the objective here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your additional information correctly, you have a SQL Server 2000 database that was created by some scripts, but the only scripts you have are in MySQL syntax and you're not sure how they are related to the SQL Server database. Your goal is to create a set of scripts that can be used to re-create the SQL Server 2000 database on a SQL Server 2008 system.

First, if that understanding is correct then I would completely forget about the MySQL scripts. They might have some value as documentation if there are useful comments in them, but they are not directly necessary for your task.

Second, I would upgrade your SQL 2000 database to SQL 2008. You can back it up and restore it on a SQL 2008 server, or you can upgrade the entire SQL Server itself from 2000 to 2008.

Third, I would generate the SQL scripts for the database objects using SQL Server Management Studio or the SMO API if you prefer. A Visual Studio database project could also be a good way to manage the scripts.

There is plenty of information on all these tasks on this site, in the SQL Server documentation, on MSDN etc. If you need more help, you should ask more precise questions about what you want to do and what you have tried already.